# Connection from Gatwick airport to Paddington station

Tags: public-transport, transportation, airport-transfer, london, lgw

What's the quickest way from Gatwick airport to Paddington station? I would like to travel as less as possible, if there is a opportiunity it would be great when there is a direct connection? ( To take a cab is the last thing I'd do )

Comment: Do you think there's a transporter or teleporter or something? What makes you believe that anything would be faster than a cab? Why is taking a cab the last thing you'd do? Are you concerned it would get stuck in traffic, or is it about the cost?

Comment: Well i dont believe that there is a teleporter or something. I was only asking if there is a better way to travel from the airport to paddington station. Maybe i will go by a transport Service like uber. Does anyone have experience with services like this? ( If it is more expensive than travelling by train it does no matter)

Comment: @ KateGregory Anyone who thinks taking a cab from Gatwick airport is the fastest way to travel to anywhere in central London, has clearly never tried to do that journey.

Comment: May we ask why you want to get to Paddington Station? If your eventual destination is somewhere reached by train from Paddington, eg Oxford, Bristol, Cardiff, Penzance, Heathrow etc, the right overall answer might actually involve not going via Paddington at all!

Comment: The final destination i am going to is only a few minutes walking away from paddington station. And i m travelling with children so i dont like to change too often. If there is something direct the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [TFL Journey Planner](http://tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey/), it'll let you find the best answer for your given time and day or travel. You can use the *Travel options & accessibility* advanced search to do things like minimise changes, minimise steps (if you have lots of luggage) etc

The quickest way will normally be to take a fast train from Gatwick to London Victoria, then a Victoria Line underground train to Oxford Circus, then a Bakerloo Line train to Paddington. The change at Oxford Circus is a cross-platform one, so no steps. You'll probably be fine to take a normal Southern service, there's little point paying the extra to save a few minutes on the Gatwick Express.

Alternately, if you want to avoid all steps, you can take a Southern Train to Victoria, then 36 bus from outside the station to Paddington. This will take 15-30 minutes longer, depending on traffic, but has no steps, and one fewer change.

You could take a Thameslink service to Blackfriars and change to a circle line train, but it'll take ages, and getting to the underground platforms isn't that easy with bags. Thameslink to Farringdon then H&C/Circle is another, that's a little quicker on the tube, but Southern/Victoria/Bakerloo is probably quicker and easier.